# Shipping methods only enabled in checkout page on Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, cart, checkout, shipping-method

On Woocommerce, we need to remove the shipping-methods from the Cart section an add it to the Checkout page only.

Any track or help should be really appreciated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be multiple ways to do it depending on the "why?" and on "for what?" you need this:

**1) Hide shipping related from cart** - The easiest way;

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_ready_to_calc_shipping', 'disable_shipping_on_cart' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping', 'disable_shipping_on_cart' );
function disable_shipping_on_cart( $enabled ){
    return is_checkout() ? true : false;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

[image]

> But it **will not remove** the shipping methods *(or shipping packages)* from session…

---

**2) Remove all shipping methods *(and shipping packages)*** everywhere except in checkout page:

```
// Shipping methods
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'keep_shipping_methods_on_checkout', 100, 2 );
function keep_shipping_methods_on_checkout( $rates, $package ) {
    if ( ! is_checkout() ) {
        // Loop through shipping methods rates
        foreach( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ){
            unset($rates[$rate_key]); // Remove
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}

// Shipping packages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_packages', 'keep_shipping_packages_on_checkout', 20, 1 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_packages', 'keep_shipping_packages_on_checkout', 20, 1 );
function keep_shipping_packages_on_checkout( $packages ) {
    if ( ! is_checkout() ) {
        foreach( $packages as $key => $package ) {
            WC()->session->__unset('shipping_for_package_'.$key); // Remove
            unset($packages[$key]); // Remove
        }
    }
    return $packages;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

[image]

> It will **remove all shipping methods** and **all shipping packages** from cart and `WC_Session`.
>
> The related registered `WC_Session` data will be something like:
>
> ```
> WC_Session_Handler Object
> (
>     [_data:protected] => Array
>         (
>             [previous_shipping_methods] => a:1:{i:0;a:3:{i:0;s:16:"free_shipping:10";i:1;s:12:"flat_rate:14";i:2;s:15:"local_pickup:13";}}
>             [shipping_method_counts] => a:1:{i:0;i:3;}
>             [chosen_shipping_methods] => a:1:{i:0;s:16:"free_shipping:10";}
>         )
> )
> ```
>
> without shipping package…
>
> It will only keep the previous shipping methods and the previous chosen shipping method for customers that have already purchased something before.

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot. Aaaand! Ive you are using Germanized, there ist a checkbox. Uncheck it and you be able to see the shipping method on checkout.
Thank you