# How to display shipping methods on checkout page and calculate shipping rate in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

How can I display shipping methods on checkout page instead of cart page and calculate shipping rate with product price on change shipping method.

I have tried *[Shipping methods only enabled in checkout page on Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53582511/shipping-methods-only-enabled-in-checkout-page-on-woocommerce/53583484#53583484)* answer code addition.

It's `removed` shipping methods on **cart page** but shipping methods is not `showing` on **Checkout Page**

I have also tried to display shipping methods on checkout page, methods is showing using following function but shipping rate is not calculating.

```
wc_cart_totals_shipping_html
```

This hooks is working for cart page but still shipping method is not showing on checkout page, How can I show shipping methods on checkout page?

[image]

I have added a image of checkout page , currently my checkout page is showing shipping method but once i change shipping method , cost will not updated with total. It's still showing $18 instead of $28.

Comment: Shipping method is display on checkout page but once I change any method it'll not reflect with grand total. I mean shipping method will not update on change option in checkout page. I have used wc_cart_totals_shipping_html for display method in checkout page,

Comment: Your question is really unclear and not understandable actually… You should try to rewrite it and better explain what you are trying to do with all requires details to make it clear and understandable. Also we expected you to provide in your question your own real code attempt. Please note that StackOverFlow is not a free coding service.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, I want shipping method workable same like on cart page but currently shipping method is showing on checkout page but not update rate on change method

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, I have updated my question, I have added a checkout page image and mentioned my issue.

Answer (score 0):

/*
I think add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates') woocommerce hook is globle hook so if you just want to hide from cart page then there is one option available in woocommerce->settings->shipping->shipping options->Enable the shipping calculator on the cart page

we can enable/disable from this options */

Comment: I have already enabled Enable the shipping calculator on the cart page but shipping calculating is not working on checkout page

Comment: 1) Enable the shipping calculator on the cart page > disable

2) Hide shipping costs until an address is entered > disable

make sure u test your cart/ checkout page on different computer or clear cache if there is any caching issue

Comment: You mean to say , I have to  uncheck both options in admin right?

Comment: I have disabled both but still not calculating shipping rate on checkout page, I used wc_cart_totals_shipping_html to display shipping method on checkout page. I also removed caching but shipping rate is not calculating  based on change method on checkout page

Comment: Not working , I want to calculate shipping rate based on change shipping method on checkout page